# Proving a conjecture given a set of clauses - calculating complexity

Tags: perl, complexity

I have written this Perl program to prove a conjecture given a set of clauses. I've actually posted some code from it on here in another question.

This time it's all done, and I've made it as fast as I need to make it.

Now, I want to calculate the Big O notation of the program. It's something I want to get better at because I learned it in a class last year, but I was never very good at it.

I believe the Big O to be \$O(n^4)\$, but like I said, I'm no expert so I'm asking you to help me out.

Also, feel free to criticize my code if you feel it's sub-par.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;
#use warnings;
use Getopt::Long; #use with options 
$|=1;

# This program uses resolution refutation, using a breadth-first and set of
# support strategy to generate a proof(if possible) and relay the results to
# the user.  

# Subsumption can be turned on with the --sub option. 
# This is recommended in most cases. 

#Algorithm:
#1.) Add the negation of the conjecture to the SOS set.
#2.) For each clause (S) is the SOS.
#   3.)For each clause (C) in the knowledge base
#       4.) Compare clause S to clause  C
#       5.) If subsumption is possible, perform subsumption.
#       6.) If resolution is possible, perform the resolution.
#       7.) If the newly generated clause is the null clause: Go to 13.
#       8.) Otherwise, check to see if the newly generated clause is already in
#       the knowledge base:
#           9.) If the clause is already in the knowledgebase: Go to 3.
#           10.) Else (if the clause is not already in the knowledge base):
#               11.)Add the clause to the SOS.
#               12.)Add the clause to the knowledge base
#13.) If the null clause was generated, you have proved the conjecture to be
#true. If it was not generated, the conjecture was false.
#14.) Inform the user accordingly

my $conclusion;
my $conclusion2;
my @conclusion;
my @SOS;
my @clauses;
my $found=0;

my $subsumption=0;
GetOptions( 'sub' => \$subsumption);


#batch mode
if($ARGV[0])
{
    my $filename = $ARGV[0];
    
    open(IN, "<", $filename);
    chomp(@clauses=<IN>);   
    close(IN);

    #additional clean up
    for(@clauses)
    {
        $_ =~ s/[^A-Za-z~,]//g;
    }
    
    #negate the negation to get the desired conclusion for later
    $conclusion2=$clauses[$#clauses];
    @conclusion = split("", $conclusion2);
        
    if($conclusion[0] eq '~')
    {
            splice(@conclusion, 0, 1);
            $found=1;   
    }
    
    if (!$found)
    {
         $conclusion = "~$conclusion2";
    }
    else
    {
        $conclusion = join("", @conclusion);
    }
    
    #now break up each line and make @clauses 2d
    $_ = [split /,/ ] for @clauses;

}

#interactive mode
else
{
    my $count=0;

    say "Welcome to my Theorem Prover!";
    say "How many clauses are in your knowledge base?";
    say "(this does not include the conclusion)";
    print "Amount: ";
    
    my $amt = <>;
    
    say "Enter your clauses: ";
    say "Negations can be indicated with a '~'.";
    say "Variable names must contain only letters.";
    say "Separate each literal with a ',' and be sure not to use the same";
    say "variable twice in the same clause\n"; 
    
    while($count < $amt)
    {
        print "clause $count:";
        $clauses[$count] .= <>;
        $clauses[$count] =~ s/[^A-Za-z~,]//g;
        $count++;
        print "\n";
    }


    print "\n \n \n Enter the conjecture, the conjecture should be a literal:";
    $conclusion = <>;   
    $conclusion =~ s/[^A-Za-z~]//g; 
    print "\n";

    #negate the conclusion and add it to the set of clauses. 
    @conclusion = split("", $conclusion);
    if($conclusion[0] eq '~')
    {
        splice(@conclusion, 0, 1);
        $found=1;
    }
    if (!$found)
    {
         $conclusion2 = "~$conclusion";
    }
    else
    {
        $conclusion2 = join("", @conclusion);
    }   
    
    #add the new conclusion and make @clauses 2d
    $_ = [split /,/ ] for @clauses;
    $clauses[$count][0] = $conclusion2;
}

#sort all clauses
for my $unsorted (0 .. $#clauses)
{
    @{ $clauses[$unsorted] } = sort ( @{ $clauses[$unsorted] });
}

print "Beginning search ....";

##################################################
#Begin search algorithm

$SOS[0][0] = $conclusion2;
my $initial = $#clauses;
my $offset = 1;
my %known_clauses;
for my $i (0 .. $#clauses) 
{
    my $key = join ( '', sort(@{$clauses[$i]}));
    $known_clauses{$key} = $i;
}

my $subs = 0;
say "\nworking......";
my %generated_with; #for use when printing
my $flag = 0; #for use when printing
SOS_ROW:
for (my $sos_row = 0; $sos_row <=$#SOS; $sos_row++) 
{

    &display_status($sos_row);

    my $current_sos_row = $SOS[$sos_row];

    CLAUSE_ROW:
    for (my $clause_row = 0; $clause_row <= $#clauses ; $clause_row++) 
    {
        
        if($subsumption)
        {
            my $matches = 0;
            for (@{$SOS[$sos_row]})
            {
                if ($_ ~~ @{$clauses[$clause_row]})
                {
                    $matches++;
                }
            }
            my $size = @{$clauses[$clause_row]};
            if ($matches == $size)
            {
                splice (@clauses, $clause_row, 1);
                $clause_row--;
                $subs++;
            }
        }


        my $current_clause_row = $clauses[$clause_row];
        my @new_clause = sort (&resolves($current_sos_row,$current_clause_row));
        my $new_clause = join ('', @new_clause);
        if(!($new_clause eq '0'))
        {
            #resolution occurred, so check to see if 
            #the clause already exists before adding it in. 
            if( exists $known_clauses{$new_clause})         
            {
                next CLAUSE_ROW;
            }
            
            #okay its new, so add it to the sets
            push(@SOS, \@new_clause);
            push(@clauses, \@new_clause);
            my $current_clause = $initial + $offset;
            $known_clauses{$new_clause} = $current_clause;
            
            #also, remember which clauses generated this one
            my $g1 = $known_clauses{join ('', @{$current_clause_row})};
            my $g2 = $initial + $sos_row;
            $generated_with{$current_clause} = "($g1,$g2)"; 
            
            #if resolution occurred, but $new_clause is empty
            $offset++;
            if(!$new_clause)
            {
                $flag = 1;
            }
            
            if($flag == 1)
            {
                last SOS_ROW;
            }
        }
    }
}
open(RESULTS, ">", 'results.txt');
say RESULTS "\n";
&printClauses;
if($subsumption)
{
    say RESULTS "\n\n $subs subsumptions were made.";
}

if($flag)
{
    say RESULTS "\n\nGood news! A resolvent was found and the empty set was generated."; 
    say RESULTS "This means that when the negation of '$conclusion' is added to the knowledge base, a contradiction renders the knowledge base false."; 
    say RESULTS "Because we know that the clauses in the knowledge base are actually true, we can soundly conclude that '$conclusion' must also be true.";
    say RESULTS "The clauses generated by each resolution can be found above.\n\n\n"; 
}
else
{
    say RESULTS "\n\nUnfortunately, we were not able to generate the empty clause.";
    say RESULTS "This means that adding the negation of the desired conclusion does not create a contradiction in our knowledge base.";
    say RESULTS "Therefore, we can not safely conclude that '$conclusion' is true.";  
    say RESULTS "Any clauses that we were able to generate through a resolution can be viewed above\n\n\n";
}
print `more results.txt`;


close(RESULTS);


#if a resolution is possible, return the new clause as an array
#if not, return 0.
sub resolves
{
    my $removed;
    my @sosR = @{$_[0]};
    my @clauseR = @{$_[1]};
    my %seen;
    for(@sosR)
    {
        $seen{$_}= 1;
    }
    SOS:
    for my $i (0 .. $#sosR)
    {
        for my $j (0 .. $#clauseR)
        { 
            if("$sosR[$i]" eq "~$clauseR[$j]"
            || "$clauseR[$j]" eq "~$sosR[$i]")
            {
                splice(@sosR, $i, 1);
                splice(@clauseR, $j, 1);
                $removed = 1;
                last SOS;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$removed)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(@clauseR)
    {
    if(!$seen{$_} )
    {
        push(@sosR, "$_");
    }
    }
    
    return @sosR;
    
}

sub display_status 
{
   my ($round) = @_;
    print "\n" if $round % 35 == 0;
    print ".";
}


sub printClauses
{
    foreach my $name (sort { $known_clauses{$a} <=> $known_clauses{$b} } keys %known_clauses) 
    {
    
        my $indx = $known_clauses{$name};
        my $clause = "clause $indx:\t";
        $clause .= "{";
        my @name = split ('', $name);
        for my $i (0 .. $#name)
        {
            $clause.= $name[$i]; 
            unless ($i == $#name || $name[$i] eq "~")
            {
                $clause .= ",";
            }
        }
        $clause .= "}";
        #will generate some  warnings (because the initial clauses have no parents to print)
        printf RESULTS ("%-25s\t%15s\n", $clause, $generated_with{$known_clauses{$name}});    
        if($indx == $initial)
        {
             say RESULTS "____________________________________________________________________";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some sample input-output to help you understand:

Command line usage: `perl ResRef.perl clauses.txt`

Input file: clauses.txt

```
a,b,c 
~b,c
~c 
~a
```

(The clauses in the knowledge base are the first 3 lines, and the last line is the negated conjecture, so we are trying to prove `a` is true.)

Output would be something like this:

```
clause 0: {a,b,c} 
clause 1: {~b,c} 
clause 2: {~c} 
clause 3: {~a}
________________________ 
clause 4: {b,c}      (0,3) 
clause 5: {c}        (1,4) 
clause 6: {b}        (2,4) 
clause 7: {}         (2,5)
```

Good news!  We found the empty clause.

Comment: Why is `use warnings;` commented out? You should also add `use strict;`.

Comment: Also, Perl has cool things like `$flag = 1 unless $new_clause`. Not sure if you purposely avoided it – I'm actually not sure if this could be considered bad practice (I'm not that proficient in Perl).

Comment: use 5.14 takes care of use strict and I turned off the warnings after I was done writing the program because It always produces some annoying warnings in the beginning. I know why they appear and it doesn't effect the program.

Answer (score 1):

### Warnings

The first item on every Perl code review is to make sure the code has:

```
use warnings;
```

along with `strict`, of course.  I realize that you justified commenting
this code out in a comment on your question.  However, it is well worth the
extra code required to fix the warning while it is fresh in your mind.

The problem is that when I run the code, I see the warning, and I don't
expect to see a warning like you do.  Therefore, I assume there is a bug in
the code.  If you run your code a year after you wrote it, there's a good
chance you won't remember to expect a warning either.

Furthermore, you are disabling other potential warnings.  Assume your code
has an unknown bug in it.  Then assume you give your code a different input
file that has a mistake in it which causes the code to malfunction in a
way that was not easily observable.  The `warnings` pragma helps to find
bugs in your code.

### Experimental code

I realize I am posting this answer nearly 10 years after the question
was posted.  This means many versions of Perl have come and gone in that
span.  I am running the code on version 5.24, and I see this message:

```
Smartmatch is experimental
```

which points to this line:

```
            if ($_ ~~ @{$clauses[$clause_row]})
```

This feature is [scheduled for removal](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11153110).

### Documentation

It is great that you added comments at the top of your file which describe
the purpose of the code.  However, the code needs usage documentation as well.

The standard way to document code in
Perl is to use plain old documentation ([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod))
in conjunction with the [Pod::Usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod::Usage) module.

The POD should include:

- Summary of the code's purpose
- A description of the optional input file
- A description for the command line option
- A description of the output file
- A few examples of common usage

### Options

Check the return value of the `GetOptions` function.  Typically, the code
should `die` if the function did not succeed.  For example, what if the
user made a typo on the command line, typing `-sbu` instead of the expected
`-sub`.  It would be better for the code to stop instead of proceeding to do
the unintended thing.

```
GetOptions('sub' => \$subsumption) or die 'Error';
```

### Namespace

It is best to import only what is needed to avoid namespace pollution.
For example, change:

```
use Getopt::Long;
```

to:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
```

### Input checking

In the interactive mode, you should remove the newline character
from data received on the standard input using
[chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp):

```
my $amt = <>;
chomp $amt;
```

It would be a good idea to also check for invalid input.  For example,
if you expect a number and someone mistakenly types a word, it would
be good to end the program with an error (or repeatedly loop until
valid input is entered).

### Linting

[perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic)
identifies several style issues.  Run it yourself to see the full report.
Here are a select few.

Don't call functions with a leading ampersand.  Change:

```
&printClauses;
```

to:

```
printClauses();
```

Use lexical file handles instead of bareword file handles and check
the success of `open`.  Change:

```
open(RESULTS, ">", 'results.txt');
```

to:

```
open $fh, '>', 'results.txt' or die "Error: file results.txt $!";
```

In the `printClauses` sub, you have two variables with the same name: `name`.  I recommend renaming the array from `@name` to `@names` to avoid confusion.